# Application.InchesToPoints in word interop doesn't works

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

in my application I use

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

and now I need to change my table column width to 3 cm and as I understand standard methods use points not cm or inches, so I wanna to convert it to points. As I read in MSDN there must be function InchesToPoints (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.inchestopoints(v=office.14).aspx)

But when I use this code

```
wordtable.Columns[0].Width = Application.InchesToPoints(3f / 2.54f);
```

there is an exception:

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.Application' does not contain a
>   definition for
>   'InchesToPoints'  Z:\porn\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs   194 62  WindowsFormsApplication3

What should I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application` refers to the hosting application in VBA.

From outside you need to use `word.InchesToPoints` (where `word` is the Word instance variable).

Comment: Yeap, but I couldn't create instance variable, coz ` 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' `  this one returned me after this code: ` Word word = new Word(); `

Comment: You seem to be using [namespace aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2325097/11683) without understanding what it is. Don't use it then. `var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();`.